# CSS on iPhone 6 - Why don't DIVs line up?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, iphone-6

I'm building a landing page optimized for iPhone users, and I'm having trouble getting the fields in my form and the button in the form to line up correctly. Things look fine on my computer (using latest version of Chrome) but on both Chrome and Safari on iPhone, the right edge of the "Get My Music" button doesn't line up with the Name and Address form fields. Here's the page:

http://radionowheresongs.com/ig2017.html

I assume that the cause is some simple little CSS gremlin that I can't find - any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, add the following css:

```
.af-element.buttonContainer {
    width: 100%;
}

div#af-form-793499238 {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
}
```

The display one could be:

```
    display: flex;
    display: inline-grid;
    display: inline-flex;
```

Any one works.

[image]

Let me know if it works for you.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Timba - one thing about this: though the form now looks fine on iPhone, the button and fields no longer line up when viewed on my laptop (which makes sense, I guess). Can you tell me how to set the CSS up so that the form displays correctly on both computer and iPHone? Thx!

Comment: Hey radionowhere, if the styles were working already for laptops maybe you only need to set up the styles that I told you just for iPhones. Try the following media query for iPhone 6: @media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}